# Printing text before reading input not working [Clojure]

Tags: clojure

As this is my first question on SO, I brought a question that's been bugging me for a couple hours.
I began "playing" with Clojure some days ago, and have crossed with a rather interesting behaviour when dealing with text printing.

I wrote a small program to take a number as input and print either "ok" or "not ok" when it'd be a multiple of 3 or not. I also added a line of code to print text asking for the user to input a number before reading a line from `stdin`. The thing is, this `print` instruction is before the `read-line` instruction, still it doesn't print to the screen. I mean, not before actually reading from `stdin`.

What exactly could the problem be? I don't come from the Lisp world (in fact, CLojure is my first Lisp-like language), so I don't really get why that's happening. Any help will be much appreciated.

The code:

```
(defn ok [n]
  (if (= (mod n 3) 0)
    "ok"
    "not ok"))

(defn main []
  (print "Type a number: ") ; This actually prints *after* the read-line instruction
  (flush) ; EDIT: The flush function is the missing part of the code. It's all ok now.
  (let [n (Integer/parseInt (read-line))]
    (println (ok n)))
  (recur)) ; it is supposed to run until Ctrl-C is signalized

(main)
```

And an image of the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Cu0.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for the clear concise question. I think the answer to the above question should cover this. It if does not, please follow up here and I'll remove the duplicate mark

Comment: Hi, @ArthurUlfeldt. Thanks for the warm welcome AND the link for a solution (which worked great). Turns out my question really is a duplicate. Anyway, thanks!